# Express API only returns first key value pair of object

Tags: javascript, express

I'm fetching nested object data. I can get that object data on console but when I try to get that data like `return res.json(imageObject)` I only get first key value pair of that object. This is the error to the console. `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.
Console data is like this `{ bigImage: 'https://url.com' }`

```js
router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
  //...fetch data
  if (mediaData.type === "type1") {
    let allData = await mediaData.media;

    allData.map(async(Data) => {
      if (Data.imageType === "big") {
        let bigImage = await Data.url;
        let imageObject = {
          bigImage
        };
        console.log(imageObject);
        return res.json(imageObject);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `res` inside a `.map`, which will trigger it once for every item in the array you're iterating.

You can't do that. You can only use `res` once for each `req`, because you're replying to the browser. If you use it more than once, you get this error, which means it's already been used and you have already replied.

Solution : use `res` once, not inside a `map`.

Also, `.map` is useless here, because you're not interested in the result it produces. You should use `forEach` or even better, a `for` loop (which is breakable on condition).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `for..of`.

It will stop the execution of your function at the return statement

```
router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
  //...fetch data
  if (mediaData.type === "type1") {
    let allData = await mediaData.media;

    let pendingResult = allData.filter(data => data.imageType === "big").map(async item => {
       let bigImage = await item.url;
       return { bigImage }
    });
    
    let result = await Promise.all(pendingResult);

    res.json(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesnt work. still only returns 1 key value pair

Comment: @rojass other question, how does your expected result should look like? could you provide some exapmle

Comment: i'm expecting all image urls like this { {bigImage: 'url'}, {bigImage: 'url'} }

Comment: @rojass `{ {...}, { ... } }` its a invalid syntax

Comment: @rojass i guess you want an array, try this out

Comment: Yes I am looking for array output